# Find the double integral $\int_{0}^1 \int_{y}^1 e^{x^2} \ dx \ dy $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need assistance to solve the double integral
$$
\int_{0}^1 \int_{y}^1 e^{x^2} \ dx \ dy. 
$$
So far I have done some poor attempts to rewrite the integral $\int e^{x^2} \ dx$ where I let $t= e^{x^2}, \ $ which lead to $\ln(t)={x^2}$, differentiating then gives $\frac{dt}{t}\ = 2x \ dx$. After some back and forth I end up with the not so nice expression $\int e^{x^2} \ dx=\frac{1}{2} \int\left(\frac{1}{\ln(t)}\right)^{1/2} \ dt$.

The answer to the double integral is $$
\int_{0}^1 \int_{y}^1 e^{x^2} \ dx \ dy=\frac{1}{2}(e-1), 
$$
but I would like some one to give me a hint on how to reach the conclusion.

Any assistance is appreciated./Pablo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that$$\int_0^1\int_y^1e^{x^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_0^1\int_0^xe^{x^2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1xe^{x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Fantastic! So nice. Now I can see the solution... Thanks alot...

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the exercise is that you won't be able to write an antiderivative for $e^{x^2}$. So what you need to do is flip the order of integration, which requires expressing your region in a different way.